# Microsoft Azure - What is the difference between Export Template vs. Download Support file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-synapse

In have some pipelines in my Azure Synapse workspace that I want to move to a different Azure subscription. I heard you can do it using `Export/Import` functionality of [Azure ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/). But a Microsoft team member @PRADEEPCHEEKATLA-MSFT describes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403992/azure-data-factory-v2-arm-template-to-synpase-data.html) (in an accepted answer to a relevant question) how you can achieve the same using `Support Files`.

In my Synapse Pipeline, I do see the options (shown in image below) for importing/exporting `Support Files`, and Importing/Exporting ARM Templates, as well.

**Question**: What is the difference between Support Files and ARM Templates when migrating a Azure Synapse Pipeline (similar to Azure Date Factory) to a different subscription. Which one is better, simpler method to use?

Export Template and Download Support Files option (shown on the right below):

[image]

Import options for Template and Support Files (shown on the left below):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We tried exporting the pipeline in both ways (download file, and export template) in our local environment. As per my knowledge and after comparing the exported data I would suggest you to use the download support files option as because.

1. Download support files option will give you end-to-end information about that pipeline by separating each file used in that pipeline with complete data. of the dataset, linked service, pipeline, etc.
2. Export template won't give end-to-end information, it will give us only the schema of that pipeline.

[image]